# Why does my thread stop when I try to access a synchronized list?

Tags: java, synchronized

For some reason, the output of this:

```
 public void msgNeedParts() {
    // Blabla...
    System.out.println(name + ": Try to print 'tasks'...");
    synchronized(tasks) {
        System.out.println(name + ": Tasks--" + tasks);
        System.out.println(name + ": Did I manage to print it?");
        tasks.add(new BinToDump(feeder, binNum));
    }
    stateChanged();
 }
```

Just prints out "GantryAgent: Try to print 'tasks'..." but not any of the following messages. I'm guessing the thread somehow 'gets stuck' when trying to access the synchronized list 'tasks', but I don't know why this is happening.

'tasks' was declared and initialized like this:

```
private List<BinToDump> tasks = 
    Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<BinToDump>());
```

Can anybody point out what I'm missing?

Ah! I suspect I may have a culprit:

```
    /* If nothing left to do, return to original position. */

    synchronized (tasks) {

        if (tasks.isEmpty()) {

            doReturnToOriginalPos();

        }

    }
```

In my scheduler (this is an agent design), I check to see if 'tasks' is empty, then I call doReturnToOriginalPos(). Maybe this is just happening over and over so fast that other methods don't get a chance to modify it?

That was indeed the problem! It kept getting called so fast in my scheduler that nothing else could access 'tasks'. Thanks all for the help!

Comment: Post all the code that accesses the 'tasks' collection. Somewhere you you're locking out access to it, or have a deadlock.

Comment: Besides the declaration/initialization, the code I posted should have been the first time 'tasks' gets accessed, but I'll work on posting the rest of it up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something has a lock on tasks. Depending on what sort of application this is, you should be able to get a full stack dump of the system, but the method varies. For example, I think CTRL-Break on most windows-based appservers will do this, and I think sending a SIGQUIT on linux will do the same.

Once you get a stack dump, you can look through it to try and find out which other thread has a lock on that object.

You can also use [VisualVM](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/threads.html) to get a stack dump, for the same end goal:

> You can use Java VisualVM to take a
>   thread dump (stack trace) while a
>   local application is running. Taking a
>   thread dump does not stop the
>   application. When you print the thread
>   dump you get a printout of the thread
>   stack that includes thread states for
>   the Java threads.
>
> When you print a thread dump in Java
>   VisualVM, the tool prints a stack
>   trace of the active threads of the
>   application. Using Java VisualVM to
>   take a thread dump can be very
>   convenient in cases where you do not
>   have a command-line console for the
>   application. You can use a stack trace
>   to help diagnose a number of issues
>   such as deadlocks or when an
>   application hangs.

Comment: Sometimes JVisualVM is an absolute life-saver.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that another thread is holding a synchronization lock against `tasks`?

Comment: Aha! Thanks for pointing that out--I checked with:
         System.out.println(Thread.holdsLock(tasks)); 
...And it returned false.

Comment: @FallSe7en: That method only checks if the *current* thread holds the lock (which you already knew it doesn't since it blocks forever on the acquire :-)).  If you're running with Java 6, fire up VisualVM or JConsole, connect to your process and you'll be able to see which thread is holding the lock (and its stacktrace).